# how to properly get day of the week (name) with moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Im using https://openweathermap.org/ api. It provides timezone in seconds. How to properly get day of the week (name) using moment.js?

```
 const timezoneInMinutes = 7200 / 60;
 const currentDate = moment().utcOffset(timezoneInMinutes).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
 console.log(currentDate) // 2022-05-13
 console.log(moment().day(currentDate).format("dddd")); // "Sunday" ????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting `currentDate` into `day()`, you need to put it on `moment()`.

```js
const timezoneInMinutes = 7200 / 60;
const currentDate = moment().utcOffset(timezoneInMinutes).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
console.log(currentDate) // 2022-05-13
console.log(moment(currentDate).format("dddd")); // "Sunday" ????
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```